# Which approach is better for showing menu at particular location on screen when there is long press in android WebView?

Tags: android, menu, android-webview

I want to show menu at particular location on screen upon longpress in WebView. So I managed to do so using following two approaches. But I have little query regarding performance and all other aspects. From below 2 approaches which one is better?

**Approach 1:**
This approach uses PointF to store X and Y coordinates.

```
    // class member variable to save the X,Y coordinates
    private final PointF lastTouchDownXY = new PointF();

View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener = (v, event) -> {

            // save the X,Y coordinates
            if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                lastTouchDownXY.set(event.getX(),event.getY());
            }

            // let the touch event pass on to whoever needs it
            return false;

        };

View.OnLongClickListener longClickListener = v -> {
            // retrieve the stored coordinates
            // use the coordinates for whatever
            // holderUtility.onLongPress is a function which shows menu
            holderUtility.onLongPress((int)lastTouchDownXY.x,(int)lastTouchDownXY.y);

            // let the touch event pass on to whoever needs it
            return false;
        };

 webView.setOnTouchListener(holder.onTouchListener);
 webView.setOnLongClickListener(holder.longClickListener);
```

**Approach 2:**
This approach uses GestureDetector.

```
final View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener;
final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener(activity,context));

onTouchListener = (v, event) -> {

     gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
     return false;
};


final class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener 
{
    public GestureListener( AppCompatActivity activity,Context context) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {return true;}

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event) {
       // holderUtility.onLongPress is a function which shows menu
       holderUtility.onLongPress((int)(event.getX()),(int)(event.getY()));
    }

}
```

Which approach is better in terms of performance and all other factors?